# Importing geophysical information to QGIS 2.10 Pisa

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am using QGIS 2.10 Pisa to georeference geophysical survey information.

When I import data I have black pixels around meaningful part of the image which I remove by setting the transparency to zero.  When I do this the black pixels in my geophysical image disappear as well.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: why do you need to get rid of black pixels around image?

Comment: What kind of image ?

Comment: what are the value of the black pixels? (-9999 or something?)

Comment: Search information about alpha channel or mask band.